# Is there anyway to clean HTML code via php being saved to a database?

Tags: php, mysql, html, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

I'm using **TinyMCE** to allow uses to edit a small portion of a web page.

This field is saved to a database.

Is there a regular expression I can use to clean the incoming HTML code so it avoids any **XSS/NULL/DROP** TABLES kind of attacks?

I've done this on single line inputs text/numbers etc, but not sure how to go about this when receiving an HTML string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd recommend playing with [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the PHP functions: `striptags` and `htmlspecialchars`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: This will obliterate the HTML produced by TinyMCE. He wants to allow HTML but remove any XSS threats.

Comment: @MrCode is correct. I don't want to strip any tags, just strip dangerous tags or javascripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this -

```
 function safe_sql($obj)
{
    $obj = htmlspecialchars($obj);
    $obj = str_replace('"',"&quot;",$obj);
    $obj = str_replace("'","&#39;",$obj);
    $obj = str_replace("`","&#96;",$obj);
    $obj = mysql_real_escape_string($obj);
    return $obj;
}
```

I'm using it and it's working fine.
And you can also use this function to make it normal(after you pull the data from the database) -

```
 function to_Normal($data)
{
    $data = htmlspecialchars_decode($data);

    $data = str_replace("&quot;",'"',$data);
    $data = str_replace("&#39;","'",$data);
    $data = str_replace("&#96;","`",$data);
    $data = nl2br($data);
    return $data;
}
```